# How to pass password in soap header which requires password digest

Tags: java, passwords, soapui, soap-client, wsdl2java

Bellow is the header file I am using.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-14867177">
<wsse:Username>WSADVINS</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"> gQEg0mep2fappUlJKKlA3B8K73g=
</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>o7wgBBqpzrDWOlSIBIHm7Q==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2007-02-20T19:45:56.456Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<!-- Message Body Payload Goes here -->
</soap:Body>
```

I am creating passworddigest using below code.

```
String userName="WSADVINS" ; String password1 ='QEg0mep2fappUlJKKlA3B8K73g=="; String nonce1="o7wgBBqpzrDWOlSIBIHm7Q=="; String dateTime = "2007-02-20T19:45:56.456Z";
                MessageDigest sha1;
                  String passwordDigest=null;
                  try {
                    java.security.SecureRandom random = java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                    random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
                    byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[16]; 
                    random.nextBytes(nonceBytes); 
                    String nonce = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(nonceBytes), "UTF-8");
 sha1= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                      byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(nonce.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                      sha1.update(dateTime.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                      sha1.update(password1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                      passwordDigest = new String(Base64.encode(sha1.digest(hash)));
                      sha1.reset();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            System.out.println("Generated password digest: " +passwordDigest );

              SOAPElement password = usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
            password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest");
              password.addTextNode(passwordDigest);
```

Not sure whats going wrong. Getting invalid username and password error all the time. From soap ui it works fine. Any one can help me please.

Comment: `String password1 ='` should be `String password1 ="` (starting the literal with a double quote). Or was this a copy-paste typo?

Comment: yes Mick. please ignore that

Comment: passwords are not the same - xml: " gQEg0mep2fappUlJKKlA3B8K73g=", java: "QEg0mep2fappUlJKKlA3B8K73g==" - in xml there is " g" (with space) at the prefix and there is one "=" less than in java code